# How to "append" an action to a function?

Tags: javascript, function

I wanted to create a function that I can add actions to later. I tried this:

```js
Function.prototype.appendAction = function(action) {
  let _ogFn = this
  return function(...args) {
    _ogFn(...args)
    action()
  }
}
function a() {
  console.log("foo")
}
a()
a = a.appendAction(() => console.log("bar"))
a()
```

This *does* work, but how can I make it change the function automatically? I want to make it work like this:

```js
a()
a.appendAction(() => console.log("bar")) //note it doesn't have the "a = "
a() //changed function
```

Comment: Could you explain your use case? maybe there is a better solution for it.

Also, why would you want to do such a thing? I can't imagine a more confusing thing to do, TBH. Imagine trying to figure it out what the function is doing in a script...

Comment: I wanted to make a function with user input (not with the constructor or a function string)

Comment: I want them to be able to add something specific as many times as they want. (Ofc I will make sure it’s not too much, harmful, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your scenario you could create a function decorator. This would mean defining a function (for example `fnMod`) that accepts a function `fn` and returns a decorated version that executes some *before* and *after* hooks.

```js
const a = fnMod(() => {
  console.log("foo");
});

a();
a.appendAction(() => console.log("bar"));
a();



const john = {
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 42,
  greet: fnMod(function () {
    console.log(`I'm ${this.name}.`); // <- uses `this` so use a normal function
  })
}

john.greet.prependAction((name) => {
  console.log(`Hi ${name}!`); // <- does not use `this` so both a normal function
});                           //    or arrow function will work fine

john.greet.appendAction(function () {
  console.log(`I'm ${this.age} years old.`);
});

john.greet("Jane");



function fnMod(fn) {
  const before = [];
  const after = [];
  
  function hookable(...args) {
    before.forEach(fn => fn.apply(this, args));
    const result = fn.apply(this, args);
    after.forEach(fn => fn.apply(this, args));
    return result;
  };
  
  hookable.prependAction = (fn) => {
    before.unshift(fn);
  }
  
  hookable.appendAction = (fn) => {
    after.push(fn);
  }
  
  return hookable;
}
```

You might want to tweak it to your liking. Currently both `this` and all arguments passed to the decorated function are forwarded to all hooks, which might or might not be desirable.

Comment: This worked like a charm, however the `this` seems to always be the Window object

Comment: @MrMythical Make sure you know how `this` works. Arrow functions don't have their own `this` binding so you'll have to pass a regular function and call the function upon an object. I've added an additional example.

Comment: Right, that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to call it immediately:

```js
Function.prototype.appendAction = function(action) {
  let _ogFn = this
  return (function(...args) {
    _ogFn(...args)
    action()
  })()
}
function a() {
  console.log("foo")
}
a.appendAction(() => console.log("bar"))
```

That is the [immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: This is not what I want. I want the variable `a` to be changed so that I can use it later. But to avoid messy syntax, I want to do it without `a = a.appendAction(...)`. This never changes `a`, only calls `a` with another action.

Comment: Why not to call your `a` function and then whatever array of user defined functions stored wherever you want?

Comment: I want the function to automatically save after having an appended action

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes you could use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

First, grab the user input however you are handling it and parse it as a string.

Then use eval like so:

```js
let userInput = 'console.log("hello world")';

const callUserFunction = (action) => {
  eval(`function fn(){${action}}`);
  fn();
}

callUserFunction(userInput);
```

Be aware that allowing a user to write or JS is a security risk, which can open doors to all kinds of attacks, so **in most scenarios, I would discourage doing so**

Comment: @MrMythical This also avoids altering the definition of a function, which seems like a bad practice, to say the least :)

Comment: I already know how to do this, and this is not what I wanted.

Comment: This solves the requirement you explained before. Is there anything else missing here? If so, could you provide a better explanation on why such a thing is necessary/required?

Comment: *"not with the constructor or a function string"*
You must have misunderstood. I meant I would make certain buttons to add the actions

Comment: Ok, so you want the user to push a button that generates a function which can be called or is directly called by the script. Why is it necessary to overwrite a function definition for this to be accomplished? The above script can do that as well.

Comment: For example: Adding the actions so that they can all be executed with a `submit` button